# How do I send all customers an order confirmation email?

Tags: magento2, admin, email

Our smtp email bugged out and didn't send order confirmation emails to over a thousand customers. How would I send them all an email? If i can't selectively send emails to people who haven't got one, how would I send an order confirmation email to everyone who ordered?

There's only one button that does that and it would take absolutely forever if I individually sent the link

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Magento has nothing out of the book that does this. So, I've created a small admin module that adds an "Order Emails" menu item to the SALES menu. From here you can filter or sort a grid of orders, and either send individual emails or select multiple emails to mass send confirmations.

Feel free to use this if you wish (https://github.com/nwcasebolt/magento-order-emails). Here's an example screenshot.

[image]